# Remove negative numbers from a matrix

Tags: python, matrix

I'm trying to replace all the negative numbers in the matrix with their positive equivalents. My problem is that adding them again in the `for` loop always skips the middle value and I don't know how to iterate through the for loop again.

I tried using a `while` loop but didn't get to a solution.
You can find my code so far here:

```
def replaceNegatives (matrix):
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        for num in matrix[i]:
            while num < 0:
                if num < 0:
                    matrix[i].remove(num)
                    num = num * -1
                    matrix[i].append(num)

    return matrix


testMatrix = [[-4, -7, -9], [-2, -4, -6], [2, 4, -5]]
print(replaceNegatives(testMatrix))
```

Prints:

```
[[-7, 4, 9], [-4, 2, 6], [2, 4, 5]]
```

Comment: Should it replace the values inside the same matrix? If so, it is confusing that it also returns the matrix, since the changes are done in place. If you want to return a new matrix instead, it can be done without using `remove` or `append`.

Comment: to create a new matrix would also be possible. I lack however still the knowledge, why I could not implement that unfortunately but then I try it so. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "remove". It seems like you are trying to just replace it with the positive value. Am I right? I think the desired printout would help much to explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: [[4, 7, 9], [2, 4, 6], [2, 4, 5]] Yes that's exactly what I want to do!

Comment: You don't need to use `remove` or `append`, because you can just reassign values inside the list like `matrix[i] *= -1`

Comment: note that this is commonly called "the absolute value", using [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions) in Python you could do this as `[[abs(v) for v in row] for row in testMatrix]` but I'd suggest looking into Numpy if you're doing lots of matrix operations, as it's just [`np.abs(testMatrix)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.absolute.html) then

Answer (score 1):

So if you want to change negative values to positive:

```
def replace_negatives(matrix):
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
            if matrix[i][j] < 0:
                matrix[i][j] *= -1

test_matrix = [[-4, -7, -9], [-2, -4, -6], [2, 4, -5]] 
replace_negatives(test_matrix)
print(test_matrix)
```

And it is important to understand that you this code changes the original matrix. So if this is what you want, it is common behaviour to return nothing to emphasise, that the new result is in the original place, not in the return value.

P.S. The construction `*= -1` means to multiply by -1 and assign no the original value, so it is a short version of `matrix[i][j] = -1 * matrix[i][j]`

Comment: Alright thank you very much for the nice explanation!